# Array search to return similar array key

Tags: php, arrays

I am not sure what should be title of this question, If you have better option, don't hesitate to change.

I need to search in an `array` with team's full name and return the short name. Now I have the following creteria:

```
$teams = array('MMB' => 'Mumbai', 'MMB' => 'Mumbai Indians');

$Vteam = (array_search($vteam, $teams, true) !== false) ? array_search($vteam, $teams) : substr($vteam, 0, 3);
```

When I search for **'Mumbai Indians'**, it returns **'MMB'**, but when I search for **'Mumbai'** alone it returns **'Mum'**.

I have around 50 team names in `$team` array.

How should I code so that on **'Mumbai'** and **'Mumbai Indians'** search it returns me **'MMB'** always?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: same name keys will override the data value

Comment: Actually I have no control over data, Its from some API. How should I perform this operation.

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: How is the API actually returning the data - show the response you're getting

Comment: What swapnesh is saying is that your example `$teams` array is impossible. You can either have `$teams = array('MMB' => 'Mumbai');`, or `$teams = array('MMB' => 'Mumbai Indians');`. It is literally 100% impossible to have your array: `$teams = array('MMB' => 'Mumbai', 'MMB' => 'Mumbai Indians');`, because there are two identical keys, and one of the values will be overwritten.

Comment: Why are you searching a map for keys using values?

Comment: @Harpreet are you sure with the `$teams` data via API??

Comment: @nickb Nice explanation :)  Btw, Can we determine which value will be overwritten or it is implementation dependent ?

Comment: @Vivek later one will supersede the prev one

Comment: It's probably last-come first-served, so I would expect (but not tested) that the OPs example code will always be identical to `$teams = array('MMB' => 'Mumbai Indians');`.

Comment: @swapnesh Actually What I get is ('Mumbai', 'Mumbai Indians') both need to have same shortname. `$team` array is created by myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're creating the `$teams` array by yourself, then form it properly with an array for the values!

```
$teams = array('MMB' => array( 'Mumbai', 'Mumbai Indians'));
```

However, if you want a lookup of the short name, invert this design:

```
$teams = array( 'Mumbai' => 'MMB', 'Mumbai Indians' => 'MMB');
```

Now, if you want to know `Mumbai`'s short name, just index the array on their name:

```
echo $teams['Mumbai']; // Output: MMB
echo $teams['Mumbai Indians']; // Output: MMB
```

Comment: That may help, I think I may search for with `array_key_exists` or
`array_keys`

Comment: @Harpreet - You don't need those (expensive) search operations. You have `$vteam`, which is the name of the team you want to find. If you form the second array, then you can directly find the short name in `O(1)` time: `echo $teams[$vteam];`. No linear searching required.

Comment: That is a great tip, Thanks @nickb

Comment: @Harpreet yeah sure and if any problem..once again welcome on stack :)  and I believe nickb done his part as well for the question

Comment: Thanks to you @swapnesh as well. You lay the foundation to the solution. That is why I love stack...

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing partial match you will probably need to use a foreach loop:

```
$search = 'Mumbai';
$team = '';
foreach($teams as $shortname => $longname) {
    if(strpos($longname,$search) !== false) {
        $team = $shortname;
        break;
    }
}
```